# Get last timestamp from an array in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, pymongo

I've got the following list of documents:

```
[
{'id': 1,
 'name': 'Coco',
 'data': [{'X': 10, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 0)},
          {'X': 20, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 2, 0)}]
},
{'id': 2,
 'name': 'Kiki',
 'data': [{'X': 30, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 10, 1, 0)},
          {'X': 40, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 4, 2, 0)}]
]
```

How do I get the last timestamp from each list in the *data* field? I would like to get something like:

```
[
{'id': 1,
 'name': 'Coco',
 'data': [{'X': 10, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 0)}]
},
{'id': 2,
 'name': 'Kiki',
 'data': [{'X': 40, 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 4, 2, 0)}]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "data": [{
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$data",
                    initialValue: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data", 0] },
                    in: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $gt: ["$$value.datetime", "$$this.datetime"] },
                            "$$value",
                            "$$this"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/3/2021, 9:15:27 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603faf17bcece4372062bcf5"),
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Coco",
    "data" : [
        {
            "X" : 10,
            "datetime" : ISODate("2020-02-01T01:00:00.000+05:30")
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/3/2021, 9:15:27 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603faf17bcece4372062bcf6"),
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Kiki",
    "data" : [
        {
            "X" : 40,
            "datetime" : ISODate("2017-11-04T02:00:00.000+05:30")
        }
    ]
}
```